# How to display images using different color maps in different figures in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to display images using different color maps in different figures.

Following code displays the image with two different windows but the same color map

```
   import scipy.misc
   from pylab import *

   a = scipy.misc.imread('lena.jpg')
   figure(1)
   image = mean(a,axis=2)
   imshow(image)
   #if I call show() here then only one window is displayed
   gray() #change the default colormap to gray
   figure(2)
   imshow(image)
   show()
```

I am wondering if anyone can please help me.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass the `cmap` argument to the imshow function. Look at http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow

Answer (score 9):

To do subplots, use the `subplot` command (!)

To change the colormap, you can use the `cmap` argument of the `imshow` function. See the [documentation](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow).

```
figure() # You don't need to specify 1
subplot(121) # 121 is a shortcut for 1 line, 2 columns, item number 1
image = mean(a,axis=2)
imshow(image, cmap='gray')
subplot(122) # 1 line, 2 columns, item number 2
imshow(image, cmap='jet')
show()
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your answer. I actually wanted to have them in different figures.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `imgplot.set_cmap('gray')`. See the huge [tutorial](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/image_tutorial.html).

Comment: Hi, you are right. It is just that Pablo answered first. I don't know how can i say both the answers are correct.

Answer (score 2):

If you are attempting to combine 2 figures into 1, i.e. make 1 image. You can use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(im1, cmap=cm.bone)
plt.imshow(im2, cmap=cm.jet,alpha=0.75)
plt.show()
```

to issue colorbars with relative colormap, call after the imshow():

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

plt.figure()

plt.imshow(im1, cmap=cm.bone)
cbar = plt.colorbar(orientation='horizontal')
cbar.set_label('Title (Unit)')

plt.imshow(im2, cmap=cm.jet,alpha=0.75)
cbar = plt.colorbar()
cbar.set_label('Title (Unit)')

plt.show()
```

Comment: NameError: name 'cm' is not defined

Comment: from matplotlib import cm

Comment: Here is an example using cm for more info:
http://matplotlib.org/1.5.0/examples/pylab_examples/multi_image.html