# Correlation Plot Color mismatch in Python using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, correlation

I am plotting correlation of data in python using  matplotlib. The highly correlated data should be coloured dark red but it is coloured as yellow in my case. How to solve it?

**My correlation data is this:**

[image: Screen shot]

**My code is like this:**

```
def plot_corr(df, size=11):

"""\
Function plots a graphical correlation matrix for each pair of columns in the dataframe.

Input:
    df: pandas Dataframe
    size: vertical and horizontal size of the plot

Displays:
    matrix of correlation between columns. Blue-cyan-yellow-red-darkred => less to more correlated
                                           0 ------------------------> 1
                                           Expect a darkred line running from top left to bottom right
"""
corr = df.corr()    #data frame correlation function
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(size,size))
ax.matshow(corr)    # color code  the rectangles by correlation value
plt.xticks(range(len(corr.columns)), corr.columns)   # draw x tick marks
plt.yticks(range(len(corr.columns)), corr.columns)   # draw y tick marks
```

**My output is like this:**

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: You need to change the colormap. See [here](https://matplotlib.org/2.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html).

Comment: To add to my comment, `matshow` has a `cmap` argument. See for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43908997/2454357), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6768946/2454357).

Answer (score 1):

Matplotlib changed the default colormap from "jet" to "viridis", the first one maps the highest value to a dark red, the second to bright yellow.

The change was not a gratuitous one, the new colormap has a number of advantages over the old one (if you are interested in the reasons why, see e.g. this [github issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/875).

One possibility is to leave the defaults undisturbed and possibly change the docstring in the part that describes the range of colours...

```
    """\
...
Displays:
    matrix of correlation between columns. Blue-teal-green-yellow => less to more correlated
                                           0 ------------------------> 1
                                           Expect a bright yellow line running from top left to bottom right.
    """
```

Another one is to explicitly mention the colormap that you want to use

```
def plot_corr(df, size=11):
    ...
    import matplotlib.cm as cm
    ...
    plt.matshow(corr, cmap=cm.jet)
    ...
```

A last possibility is to restore *ALL* the previous default of Matplotlib, either at the level of the calling program

```
plt.style.use('classic')
```

or at the level of the function

```
    ...
    with plt.style.context('default'):
        plt.matshow(corr)
        ...
```